# create img element with js and add src attribute

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm not sure how to add src to an image with js

```
//e6
    //this code create a new 'img' element
    let newElementImg = document.createElement("img");
    //this code add img from url
    newElementImg.src = "url('https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/50/24/PZpRVx.jpg')";
    //this code set a list of classes for the 'img' element
    newElementImg.classList.add("img-fluid");
    //append newElementLink to an existing element which has an 'footer-about' ID
    var imgDiv = document.getElementById('footer-about');
    imgDiv.append(newElementImg);
```

it kinda works but the image not showing just an "image broken" icon [like this][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No6Cn.gif)

Comment: If you right click and inspect your broken image, you should see what's contained in your src attribute. I think the answer you got is correct in that without the url() part it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just the address without the `url('...')`. The `url(...)` is for css.

Answer (score 0):

This is a css string:

```js
    newElementImg.src = "url('https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/50/24/PZpRVx.jpg')";
```

You don't need the url() part just the raw string:

```js
    newElementImg.src = 'https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/50/24/PZpRVx.jpg';
```